# fluentvalidation SetCollectionValidator

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

Dears
I'm trying to validate list of object using SetCollectionValidator and the the list count maybe has 0 object or more of object so the validation return error till if the list not has item like that

```
public class SCRequest
{
    public List<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
}

public class Attachment
{
    public int AttachmentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public string FileUrl { get; set; }
}
```

now for validating the `ScRequest` I do the following

```
public SCRequestValidator()
{
    RuleFor(request => request.Attachments)
        .SetCollectionValidator(new AttachmentValidator());
}
```

and for validating the Attachment I do the following

```
public AttachmentValidator()
{
    RuleFor(x => x.FileUrl)
        .NotNull()
        .WithMessage(ErrorMessage.B0001)
        .NotEmpty()
        .WithMessage("Not Allowed Empty");
}
```

I get the error not `Not Allowed Empty` when the list of attachments has 0 object, my problem I want to validate the list only when it has the values.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 7):

You can set rules/validators to only get called under certain scenarios by using When(). In your example the code will be something like:

```
public SCRequestValidator()
{
    When(request => request.Attachments.Any(), () => 
    {
     RuleFor(request => request.Attachments)
         .SetCollectionValidator(new AttachmentValidator());
    });
}
```

So if there are no attachments, the CollectionValidator will not get set.